# How to define a method in controller for testing, which we should not call from development

Tags: .net, testing, model-view-controller, controller, action

I am new to the MVC. I have a doubt that I should define a method in controller class, which should not be called from development. Because we define that method for testing purposes.

I have another doubt: if we call that method which is defined for testing, do we get 404 error?

Please clarify me. I don't know whether it is a valid question. But please if anyone knows, make me clear in this doubts.

Comment: There are many frameworks on a variety of platforms that are MVC - which one is your question about?

Comment: hi Frederick, i am using .NET framework. can you please tell me that how to do it? i guess you may got my question?..